# Tomcat 8.5.4 SSL Empty Response

Tags: tomcat, ssl, tomcat8

I recently renewed a Let's Encrypt certificate for a Tomcat server I have been running on Ubuntu.

After updating the keystore with the new fullchain.pem and restarting Tomcat, SSL requests return an empty response. Any non-SSL requests to port 80 work perfectly fine.

I created a keystore.jks with the password "password" and alias "tomcat", using the following commands:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey privkey.pem -out pkcs.p12 -name tomcat
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass password -destkeypass password -destkeystore keystore.jks -srckeystore pkcs.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass password -alias tomcat
```

In my Tomcat's server.xml, I have two connectors enabled:

```
    <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="443"
               address="serveraddress"
               maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"
                />
    <Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               maxThreads="25" scheme="https" secure="true"
               SSLEnabled="true" keystorePass="password"
               keystoreFile="conf/keystore.jks" clientAuth="false" 
               keyAlias="tomcat" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"
               address="serveraddress"
               maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"
               />
```

The curl request `curl server.com` succeeds, but `curl server.com:443` returns an empty response. I have tried both curling externally and to the port when it's bound to localhost.

I have looked this up everywhere and I still can't figure out why it's happening. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the protocol HTTPS. `curl https://server.com:443`

The 443 is optional since it is the default port for HTTPS.

"If you specify URL without protocol:// prefix, curl will attempt to guess what protocol you might want. It will then default to HTTP but try other protocols based on often-used host name prefixes. For example, for host names starting with "ftp." curl will assume you want to speak FTP."

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html